# How do I only run tests for only one package?

Tags: catkin-make, catkin, rostest

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`catkin_make run_tests --pkg costmap_2d` seems a likely candidate but doesn't work.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62583/how-do-i-only-run-tests-for-only-one-package?/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2013-05-12

Post score: 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Good question!

I didn't know either, but I did some digging, and here's what I found:

```
catkin_make run_tests_packageName
catkin_make run_tests_packageName_gtest_testTarget
```

---

*Read on for more details...*

As documented [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/catkin/conceptual_overview#Explanation_Details),

> Catkin packages use macros that define make targets prefixed with run-tests.
> They can be run by invoking catkin_make run_tests[*...]
> or just using make run_tests[*...].

Given this clue, I googled for a command to list all defined make targets, and found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063507/list-goals-targets-in-gnu-make):

```
make -qp | awk -F':' '/^[a-zA-Z0-9][^$#\/\t=]*:([^=]|$)/ {split($1,A,/ /);for(i in A)print A[i]}'
```

When I run that in my catkin workspace, I get the following targets (among others):

```
run_tests_my_package
run_tests_my_package_gtest
run_tests_my_package_gtest_my_tests
```

These targets correspond to the following lines in my `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
project(my_package)
catkin_add_gtest(my_tests test/my_tests.cpp)
```

I would assume there are similar targets defined for rostest tests, but I have not looked for these yet.

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2013-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 13

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2013-05-13**:
That's entirely intuitive.  Thanks!

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-05-13**:
This is not built into `catkin_make` because it has to work without `catkin_make`, i.e. it should work with just `cmake` and `make`. Btw, the make targets should be tab completable, so `catkin_make run_tests_` should list all of your options.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For those of you using catkin_make_isolated (and with plain cmake packages in the mix), the following seems to work well:

```
catkin_make_isolated --catkin-make-args run_tests
```

---

Originally posted by [dustingooding](https://answers.ros.org/users/3314/dustingooding/) with karma: 139 on 2014-10-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To run a catkin test for a specific catkin package, from a directory within that package:

```
   catkin run_tests --no-deps --this
```

---

Originally posted by [afakih](https://answers.ros.org/users/24990/afakih/) with karma: 206 on 2016-12-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6